# Pegar valor específico em um JSON ou em XML

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Olá, eu tenho um JSON inteiro dentro de uma string e eu preciso transformá-lo em objeto para poder acessar alguns dados... Vou deixar o código abaixo para ver se vocês podem me ajudar.

Meu JSON esta nessa string:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

parte do JSON:

```
{
"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"Windows-1252","@standalone":"yes"},
  "VFPData": {
    "row": [
      {
        "@numero": "000",
        "@descricao": "Menu principal",
      },
      {
        "@numero": "001",
        "@descricao": "Arquivos",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Eu preciso acessar os valores destes `@descrição`.

Eu estou usando **.Net Core Razor Pages**... alguém aí poderia me dar uma ajuda com isso ???

**JSON(JSON Visualizer do VS):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o `@descricao` é o `@des_mn0`, que eu preciso pegar.

**COMO ESTOU FAZENDO:**

```
public class DadosMenu
{
    [JsonProperty("VFPData")]
    public VFP vfp { get; set; }
}
public class VFP
{
    [JsonProperty("row")]
    public Row[] row { get; set; }
}
public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("@des_mn0")]
    public string des { get; set; }
}
```

(`public IActionResult OnGet(){}`):

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Dados\VS\MenuXML\menuV11.Xml");

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).ToString();

DadosMenu result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosMenu>(json);

for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    descr +=  result.vfp.row[i].des + " - ";
}
HttpContext.Session.SetString("xmltojson", descr);
```

**EDIT:** Muito bem, já estou conseguindo pegar os valores que preciso... agradeço a todos pelas respostas, e já atualizei a pergunta, mostrando como estou fazendo para pegar os valores.

Caso seja possível, se puderem fazer o mesmo (pegar um valor específico) em um XML, vai me poupar um pouco de trabalho... então vou deixar parte do XML a seguir, para que possam saber como fazer...

**OBS:**

1 - O XML se refere ao mesmo assunto do json. Eu apenas o transformei.

2 - Preciso guardar esses dados que peguei, em uma `lista`, para que eu consida depois usá-los para montar um menu.(`nav-bar`)

**(XML)**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<VFPData>
    <xsd:schema id="VFPData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="VFPData" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="num_mn0" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                            <xsd:attribute name="des_mn0" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
<row num_mn0="000" des_mn0="Menu principal"/>
<row num_mn0="001" des_mn0="Arquivos"/>
```

Preciso pegar o valor do `des_mn0`.

**EDIT2:**

erro que aparece, ao tentar a resposta do alisson:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OnGet:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

DadosMenu result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosMenu>(json);

ViewData["DadosMenu"] = result.vfp.row;

return Page();
```

Eu havia, ontem, criado uma lista que eu guardo todas as informações que preciso... eu só não sei como pegar esses dados no HTML, olha como eu fiz:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

DadosMenu result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosMenu>(json);

List<string> MenuPrincipal = new List<string>();
int i = 1;
while (result.vfp.row[i].men != "")
{
    if (result.vfp.row[i].men == "_MSYSMENU")
    {
        MenuPrincipal.Add(result.vfp.row[i].des);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

ViewData["MenuPrincipal"] = MenuPrincipal;

return Page();
```

Comment: O dado que você recebe é json mesmo?

Comment: é sim @VirgilioNovic... na verdade estou recebendo em xml e transformo para json, como mostra o código

Comment: se você está recebendo em XML não era melhor fazer por ele?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, se tiver alguma ideia de como fazer, pode deixar nas respostas... mas eu tentei da forma que o alisson comentou, mas não deu muito certo... se quiser, me fale que eu deixo parte do xml na pergunta.

Comment: Samuel eu fiz uma versão com Json, se colocar o XML depois eu faço com ele também é só postar na pergunta e adequar a isso porque você pediu com JSON.

Comment: tranquilo... daqui uns 30 Minutos eu faço as mudanças pra vc @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Acho que já está adequada @VirgilioNovic

Comment: @SamuelMachado pelo que vi no código que colocou agora, com o código que você já tem, troque na sua class VFP o Row[] por List<Row>. Então no seu result você ja terá a lista pronta, só usar result.vfp.row para acessar.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste, mas obrigado pela dica @AlissonMarqui. Então eu devo trocar, dentro da minha classe VFP, o `public Row[] row { get; set; }` por `public List<Row> row { get; set; }`?

Comment: @SamuelMachado isso, fazendo esta troca a propriedade row da class VFP sera uma lista do objeto Row, e o JsonConvert ja convert o JSON em List.

Comment: @SamuelMachado Se entendi, você quer colocar isso em uma lista para retornar para sua View como Model, certo ? se for eu edito minha resposta deixando mais completa...

Comment: @AlissonMarqui, eu preciso de pegar os valores retornados(um por um), para montar o meu menu, através destes retornos, que por enquanto terá as opções "Menu Principal" e "Arquivos"

Comment: Ótimo @AlissonMarqui... vou fazer o teste, muito obrigado

Comment: Testei o que você disse @AlissonMarqui, e realmente foi muito bom, mas eu preciso criar uma nova lista, com cada dado do meu for... Então cada item que ele for adicionando, será adicionado um novo item à nova lista de objetos

Comment: @SamuelMachado você já esta com uma lista e esta fazendo for nela, sua `List` atual é do objeto Row, você quer gerar uma List do que? não entendi o porque precisa gerar uma nova List...

Comment: Fiz a edição com XML

Comment: @SamuelMachado editei a resposta exemplificando a geração da nav-bar, de acordo com o que entendi do seu edit e dos comentarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Converter JSON**

Para fazer a conversão do JSON para objeto utilizando a bliblioteca [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) o seu model deve seguir a mesma estrutura que o seu JSON para que o componente consiga converter. As classes e as propriedades tem que respeitar os nomes do JSON para isso você pode usar a anotação `JsonProperty`.

No seu JSON você tem um objeto VFPData com um array de objeto row, que contem os dados, então seu model seria o seguinte:

**Model**:

```
public class DadosMenu
{
    [JsonProperty("VFPData")]
    public VFP vfp { get; set; }
}

public class VFP
{
    [JsonProperty("row")]
    public List<Row> row { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("@des_mn0")]
    public string des { get; set; }
}
```

Com o model criado de acordo com o JSON o DeserializeObject vai conseguir popular o objeto corretamente.

---

**Montar view**

Como você mencionou no edit da questão e nos comentários, você precisa desses dados para montar a `nav-bar` do menu na sua view.

Agora com os dados populados nos objetos, você pode no seu controller retornar a list de varias formas, acredito que as duas mais comuns seja por ViewData e por model em view fortemente tipada.

Tendo este dados na View tanto por ViewData ou Model você pode fazer o `for` e gerar sua nav-bar diretamente no Razor.

Obs: Os dois exemplos vão estar no código, basta remover o que não for usar.

Exemplo:

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult OnGet(){
    var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Dados\VS\MenuXML\menuV11.Xml");

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).ToString();

    DadosMenu result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosMenu>(json);

    // Caso queira retornar por ViewData utilize esta linha abaixo
    ViewData["DadosMenu"] = result.vfp.row; 

    // Nesta linha retornara para a View e ela deve ser anotada com 
    // @model ObjetoModelDaView
    return View(result.vfp.row);
}
```

**View**

```
// Usar essa linha se optar por Fortemente Tipada
// Esta linha é quem define o tipo da View
// Tem que ser o mesmo tipo que voce vai retornar no controller em return View(objeto)
@model List<Row>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      @{
        // Usar se optar por ViewData    
        var rows = ViewData.DadosMenu as List<Row>; 

        // Se for usar Fortemente Tipada trocar rows por Model
        // Pois o Model da view é a List<Row>
        for (Row row : rows) {
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">@row.des</a>
          </li>
        }
      }          
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ótimo... muito boa resposta, só mais uma duvida, se possível... eu preciso montar uma lista com esses valores... sei que é uma pergunta boba, mas estou começando meus estudos agora, então preciso de uma mãozinha

Comment: @SamuelMachado se a minha resposta te ajudou com o problema em questão marque como correta por favor. Quanto a outra duvida no comentário acima,  você quer criar uma pagina listando essas dados em uma table html ?

Comment: não em uma table... preciso pegar os valores e guardar em uma List<>, pra depois usá-los para montar um menu, de acordo com os valores deles... eu consegui pegar os valores de uma outra forma, e usando um `for()` para pegar todos, e está pegando todos que eu preciso mesmo, mas não sei como armazenar em uma lista

Comment: @SamuelMachado crie uma pergunta com essa duvida da lista, e coloque la como esta seu código, mande o link aqui e entro la responder, fica mais fácil, nos comentários é difícil. E quanto a essa pergunta, se minha resposta te ajudou marque-a como aceita, obrigado.

Comment: tudo bem, obrigado

Comment: acredito que haja alguns erros, como por exemplo o uso do ViewData... nao seria, no caso, `ViewData["DadosMenu"]` ao invés de `ViewData.DadosMenu`? E também deu alguns erros, tentei fazer com que me retornasse sem ser em um menu, so para checar os valores, e nao funcionou, vou deixar um print na pergunta, como `EDIT2` par você dar uma olhada.

Comment: e quanto ao `return View(parametro)`, também não funcionou... Estou usando, atualmente, um `return Page();` e pelo que li, não aceita parâmetros.

Comment: @SamuelMachado no ASP tem o ViewData e ViewBag eu escrevi da forma que se usa o ViewBag utilizando o ViewData. o ViewData é `ViewData["DadosMenu"]` e ViewBag é `ViewBag.DadosMenu`. Editei a questão corrigindo o erro, o ViewData necessita de TypeCasting na hora de recuperar a informação para saber qual objeto esta vindo nele.

Comment: Alisson, muito obrigado pela sua resposta... eu modifiquei algumas coisas para fazer funcionar... mas foi vc quem me deu a base, muito obrigado

Comment: @SamuelMachado fico feliz por ter ajudado! Ultima dica, você que esta começando com asp.net veja os conteúdos do Eduardo Pires ele tem ótimos conteúdos.

Answer (score 5):

Sugiro que use a biblioteca [Json.net que pode ser baixada aqui](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

Depois é só:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<teste>(json);
```

Onde o `teste` corresponde ao tipo de objeto que corresponde à string do seu Json.

Comment: mesmo com a sua dica, não estou conseguindo fazer com aquele json que deixei de exemplo... poderia fazer um exemplo que funcione com aquele json?

Comment: Vou deixar um print de como está o meu json, de acordo com o JSON Visualizer do VS.

Answer (score 3):

Editado a pergunta e fechando aquele `XML` que veio errado fica como exemplo:

***XML:***

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<VFPData>
    <xsd:schema id="VFPData" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="VFPData" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="num_mn0" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                            <xsd:attribute name="des_mn0" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" processContents="lax"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <row num_mn0="000" des_mn0="Menu principal"/>
    <row num_mn0="001" des_mn0="Arquivos"/>
<VFPData/>
```

Classes:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class VFPData
{
    [XmlElement("row")]
    public VFPDataRow[] Rows { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class VFPDataRow
{     
    [XmlAttribute("num_mn0")]
    public string Number { get; set; }        
    [XmlAttribute("des_mn0")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Código criando um dado tipado com essas informações:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VFPData));
using (var textReader = new StreamReader("./data.xml"))
{
    VFPData data = (VFPData)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
}
```

---

***JSON:***

Basicamente modelando para classes e com o pacote [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) configurando [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty__ctor.htm), exemplo:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("?xml")]
    public Xml Xml { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("VFPData")]
    public Vfpdata Vfpdata { get; set; }
}

public class Xml
{
    [JsonProperty("@version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@encoding")]
    public string Encoding { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@standalone")]
    public string Standalone { get; set; }
}

public class Vfpdata
{
    [JsonProperty("row")]
    public Row[] Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("@numero")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@descricao")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

e carregando o `json`:

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./data.json");
Rootobject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

[Ref. Documentação - Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

1- Você está utilizando o `Dados` como objeto de deserialização:

```c#
Dados result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dados>(json);
```

Mas o objeto a qual a string `json` se refere é o `DadosMenu`

2- Você está tentando obter a propriedade `@des_mn0` mas o JSON de exemplo tem a propriedade `@descricao`

Comment: eu coloquei na pergunta... o `@descricao` é o `@des_mn0`, que eu preciso pegar.

Comment: Sim, mas por que está utilizando a JsonProperty `@des_mn0` se no JSON está `@descricao`?

Comment: Eu modifiquei o json pra postar... oque eu quis dizer é que o `@descricao` é a mesma coisa que o `@des_mn0`... É como se fosse o homem aranha e o Peter Parker, entende?

Comment: Entendi. Mas não seria melhor deixar exatamente como está no código? Digo porque isso influencia no `sonConvert.DeserializeObject()`